# Как правильно расставить запятые

Tags: запятая

На самом деле, туристам они встречаются редко, потому что живут глубоко в лесах людям на глаза стараются не попадаться.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая в этом предложении не нужна, так как выражение "на самом деле" не является вводным в отличие от фразы "в самом деле". НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ здесь обычное обстоятельство: как? НА САМОМ ДЕЛЕ (= в действительности).